# Self referencing calculation in group by in r

Tags: r, data.table, dplyr

I am working with a dataset where I have to create a new calculation (column v2 here). I am trying to self reference the previous value of v2 and add it to present value v1, all this calculation should happen pertaining to group (group,level)

Please find the dataset below:

```
group <- c('A','A','A','A','B','B','B','B')
level <- c(1,1,2,2,1,1,1,1)
date1 <- as.Date(c('2017-1-10','2017-1-11','2017-1-10','2017-1-11',
               '2017-1-10','2017-1-11','2017-1-12','2017-1-14'))
v1 <- c(0,3,1,2,1,2,-1,3)

df <- data.frame(group,level,date1,v1)
```

I have tried to mutate and lag to create a new column v2 for my calculation

```
df$v2 <- 0
df %>% group_by(group,level) %>% mutate(v2 = v1 + lag(v2,1L,default = 0))
```

The result is as below:

[image: Please click here]

The expected result is as below:

[image: Please click here]

Please do note the dataset I will be working on will have more than 100 groups and 15 levels, so I have to automate the calculation for v2.

To give a better clarity, the formula for v2 would be = previous value of v2 + present value of v1 in the group created by group and level

Thank you so much for your time. Highly appreciate any help

Comment: `df %>% group_by(group,level) %>% mutate(v2 = cumsum(v1))`

Comment: You are awesome @RobJensen. Thank you! Just out of curiosity when did the lag function not work?

Comment: You cannot reference `v2` because it hasn't been created yet

Comment: Got it. Thank you @RobJensen

Comment: @RobJensen, you should make that an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't reference the variable you're creating in `mutate`. Luckily, the variable being created in this case can be created with `cumsum` instead.

```
df %>% group_by(group,level) %>% mutate(v2 = cumsum(v1))
```